# I'm getting error while connecting to node js server(angularjs,nodejs,mysql connection)

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "app/rooms" in views directory "E:\Angular\project1\views"
    at Function.render (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\Angular\project1\server.js:30:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Query._callback (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:491:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (E:\Angular\project1\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
```

In the directory i don't have folder like "views"  there is only src file and other json,node files. If anyone know a better way to connect to server please tell me(Any references)

---------------------THIS IS THE CODE USED FOR SERVER CONNECTION--------------

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set('view engine','html');

app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'));
app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/tether/dist/js'));
app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydb"
});

app.get('/',function(req, res){

   con.query("SELECT * FROM rooms ",function (err,result){
       res.render('app/rooms',{
          pageTitle: "Rooms List",
          items: result
       });
   });
});


var server = app.listen(4200,function(){
     console.log("Server started on 4200.....");
})
```

Comment: so did you check the content of directory "E:\Angular\project1\views" ???

Comment: Can  you please add more description, what are you doing, what is the scenario ...etc. Take a look please at "How to ask": https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the the recommendation, i updated some details@yazantahhan

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here you are already setting a view engine to render your view from the server.  But you said you are using Angular. So you don't need view engine set up.
These two codes should be deleted.  Except you are doing server rendering, whereby you want to use what to render your page from the server if so you will need a view folder.

app.set('view engine','html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

But if you are not doing anything like server rendering just delete those code relating to view.